# PyQt: How to transfer text data between widgets?

Tags: python, pyqt

So here's my problem.  I attached an image of what I'm working with to give you some visual idea of what I'm doing.   I have my list of icons at the bottom.  I have a QGraphicsView above it (with the line going through it).

http://oi43.tinypic.com/2uhx1xj.jpg (apparently I'm not able to post images yet because I'm a newbie)

So far I am able to drag and drop an icon from the bottom list into the QGraphicsView.  However, the image that's dropped into the QGraphicsView is just 1 default image that I defined as the "blender" icon.  (The code below is what I have working with 1 default image).

```
#Defined in QGraphicScene
def dropEvent(self, event):
    event.accept()
    item = QGraphicsPixmapItem(QPixmap("images/{}".format("blender")))
    item.setFlags(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsSelectable|
                  QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable)

    position = QPointF(event.scenePos())
    print(position)
    item.setPos(position)
    self.addItem(item)
```

What I WANT is the image that is dropped into the QGraphicsView to be the same image that is in the QListWidget.  For example, if "Mozilla" is dragged and dropped into QGraphicsView I want the Mozilla icon to be displayed, and etc...  I think if I can somehow get the text name transferred from the QListWidget to the QGraphicsView then I could just replace "blender" with whatever variable.

What I think I have to do is redefine the "startDrag()" function for my QListWidget and then in my QGraphicsScene, I need to implement my dropEvent() to handle that data. I've looked over QMimeData & QDataStream but am not exactly clear. I think it looks something like this:

```
#startDrag() that is reimplemented for the listWidget1 function. listWidget1 is the list in the first tab
def scene_startDrag(self, dropActions):
    item = self.listWidget1.selectedItems()
    data = QByteArray()
    stream = QDataStream(data, QIODevice.WriteOnly)
    stream.writeQString(item.text())
    mimeData = QMimeData()
    mimeData.setData("application/x-img", data)
    drag = QDrag(self)
    drag.setMimeData(mimeData)
```

If it helps, I have all of those icons in listWidget1 stored in a dictionary called "nodes" with the key being whatever the name is being displayed in the list.  So in listWidget1, Mozilla's key is just "mozilla".

So to put it simply, all I want to do is get the correct image to show up in the QGraphicsView. Sorry for the long post. Does anybody have any idea on how I can implement this? Thank you for any input!

Comment: Have you tried looking at `QDropEvent.source()` ? That will give you a widget back you'll probably be able to get the icon name from that.

Comment: You know, I'm nto too bad at PyQt, but I'm still a bit of a newbie. I looked up QDropEvent() and then looked at the source() function but didn't really get a lot of information on how to use it. Any idea where I should go to actually see what I can do with source()? Thanks for the reply!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I didn't think I'd get this one but I figured it out.  After reading more extensively about drag/drop functions I got something that works.  `QMimeData` is confusing.

Here's what I did. First re-implemented the `startDrag()` for the list widget:

```
def scene_startDrag(self, dropActions):
    item = self.listWidget1.currentItem()
    data = QByteArray()
    stream = QDataStream(data, QIODevice.WriteOnly)
    stream.writeQString(item.text())
    mimeData = QMimeData()
    mimeData.setData("application/x-imgname", data)
    drag = QDrag(self)
    drag.setMimeData(mimeData)
    drag.exec() #actually starts the dragging
```

Then in the `QGraphicsScene` that's associated with the `QGraphicsView` I reimplemented the `dropEvent()` function:

```
def dropEvent(self, event):
    if(event.mimeData().hasFormat("application/x-imgname")):
        event.accept()
        data = event.mimeData().data("application/x-imgname")
        stream = QDataStream(data, QIODevice.ReadOnly)
        text = stream.readQString()
        item = QGraphicsPixmapItem(QPixmap("images/{}".format(text)))
        item.setFlags(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsSelectable|
                      QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable)
        position = QPointF(event.scenePos())
        item.setPos(position)
        self.addItem(item)
```